# Speed of accessing a pointer

Tags: c++, performance, pointers

I'm rewriting all of the data structures I learned in school as an exercise to reinforce my understanding of the fundamentals of computer science, but I'm attempting to optimize my naïve implementations that I created when I was younger.

This lead me to a question:

I have these few lines from my linked list implementation where temp is used in both variations...

```
Node<T> *temp = head;

if(temp == nullptr) {
    ...
}

... // temp used here
```

My linked list also has an attribute `long listSize`, so the above line is analog to

```
if(!listSize) {
   ...
}

... // temp used here, too.
```

This is obvious. What is less obvious (to me) is which of these would be faster for the computer.

From what (little) I understand about pointers, any operation with them is fairly expensive, which leads me to believe that the former might be less optimal than the latter; however, I'm not entirely sure.

Can anyone help clear up this nuance for me?

Thanks, 
erip

**EDIT**

After posting this, I decided to set up an experiment. I decided to make the first implementation `method2` and the second implementation `method1`. I ran it several times on logarithmic inputs ranging from size 10M to 1B and, by and large, `method2` was faster (albeit not much - a measly 1us) than `method1`.

After a bit of contemplation, I suppose this makes sense because pointers are 8-byte on my architecture, which is the same size as a long int. Thus, the comparison to `NULL` should be a very similar process, and would probably take about the same time.

Comment: The second one seems faster because there's no assignment. But this is just guessing. Measure to find out.

Comment: In both cases a small value is compared to zero. There can be marginal differences, but even with some extremely huge relative difference the impact on your code would most likely be unmeasurable. Still, do **measure** to establish whether you can indeed see any difference or not.

Comment: @zenith the `temp` variable would still be needed later. I was speaking in terms of the `if` statement.

Comment: @erip Well, add it to the question then. Btw `if(!head)` would be possible as well.

Comment: Since `temp` is used anyway I'd guess it would be faster to assign and use it right from the start.

Comment: @zenith: Modern compilers don't care about such assignments. To them, it just says "from this point on, the particular value has **two** names". E.g. if the variable is in a register, for the next line of code both names refer to that same register. The reason is that it's cheap to shuffle names around (because names are only for the compiler) and actually moving values around from one memory location to the other takes CPU work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> From what (little) I understand about pointers, any operation with them is fairly expensive

This is not true in general: although a level of indirection (i.e. accessing something through a pointer) does have a cost, modern hardware optimizes it to the point that there is no way for you to tell in all but the most extreme cases. Aggressive caching makes this difference even smaller, so calling indirect access "fairly expensive" is not accurate.

However, in your case it's even simpler than that: there is no indirection going on at all! You are checking the value of the pointer itself, not the value of whatever it points to, so there is virtually no difference between checking a pointer and checking the length. A pointer could be 8 bytes while the length could be 4 bytes, but you wouldn't be able to tell the difference in time on modern CPUs.

Answer (score 1):

I guess both are the same. You are essentially doing logical comparison in both cases. Pointer is also a variable. It just contains address and is located in the same memory area as other variables.

However, deep down (assembly) the first case might be slower since it is using two variables instead of one.